# Passing a list of strings in Flask to javascript returns first part of list as string

Tags: javascript, json, flask

I have a list of strings `arr=['a', 'b', 'c']` that I am sending from my Flask app. I pass it to my static js script like so `arr={{arr|tojson}}` and then use `JSON.parse(arr)`.

The solutions that I've seen all seem to work on localhost but when I serve my app through a wsgi container behind nginx, my js file interprets it like so `arr="['a',"'b','c']`. At times when I `JSON.parse()` it, I recieve an `unexpected end of JSON input` error because the js file only receives `"['a',"`. Other times, it gets an `unexpected token \ at line 1` when I use `arr={{arr|tojson|safe}}`.

I've tried sending the arr from my `app.py` with `json.dumps()` `map(json.dumps,arr)`. I've tried both `{arr|tojson}}` and `{arr|tojson|safe}}`. I've tried reading the arr from my js file with and without `JSON.parse()` but no dice for all attempts.

my `app.py`

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',arr=arr)
```

my `index.html`

```
<script id="params" type="text/javascript" arr={{arr|tojson}} src="{{url_for('static',filename='app.js')}}"></script>
```

my `app.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var src = $('#params');
    arr = JSON.parse(src.attr('arr'));
});
```

Comment: did you try with json.dumps() method while returning array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my `app.py`

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',arr=arr)
```

my `index.html`

```
<script id="params" type="text/javascript" arr={{','.join(arr)}} src="{{url_for('static',filename='app.js')}}"></script>
```

my `app.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var src = $('#params');
    arr = src.attr('arr').split(',');
});
```